# Generating a random Integer between 1 and 3 excluding a variable

Tags: matlab, random, integer, probability, rounding

Using Matlab I have to generate a random integer between 1 and 3 twice, with equal probability.

```
A=round(((rand(1)*2)+1))
B=round(((rand(1)*2)+1))
```

I then have to generate another random integer C, between 1 and 3, which cannot be the same as the variables A and B.

i.e. A = 1, B = 3, C = 2 
or 
A = 2, B=2, and C could be equal to either 1 or 3.

Preferably using the "if" function.

Comment: You mean without IF, don't you?

Answer (score 2):

You should be using [`RANDI`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randi.html) to make the random integers.

```
AB = randi([1, 3], 1, 2); % Generate A and B at the same time
while true
    C = randi([1 3]);     % Make C
    if ~ismember(C, AB)   % Is C ok?
        break;            % Then terminate the loop.
    end
end
```

Or here's another approach without the loop.

```
AB = randi([1, 3], 1, 2);               % Generate A and B at the same time
possibleC = setdiff(AB, 1:3);           % All valid values of C
C = possibleC(randi(numel(possibleC))); % pick one at random.
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly

```
A=round(((rand(1)*2)+1))
```

Will pick `1` 25% of the time, `2` 50% of the time and `3` 25% of time. Which is *NOT* a uniform distribution.

What you actually wanted was

```
A=floor(((rand*3)+1));
```

To prove this try `A=round(((rand(10000,1)*2)+1))` and observe the values for `sum(A==1)/10000`, `sum(A==2)/10000` etc...

Now to get `C` try

```
S = randperm(3);
```

and proceed as Divakar has suggested i.e.

```
C = S(S~=A & S~=B);
C = C(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
lin_ind = 1:3;
out = lin_ind(lin_ind~=A & lin_ind~=B);
C = out(1)
```

Comment: This will be biased towards choosing lower value for `C` in cases when `A==B`. Rather use `lin_ind = randperm(3)`

Comment: You are right. I am actually not considering probability at all. I was just assuming that the probability criteria is only for A and B, which would be taken care by OP's code.

Answer (score 0):

```
A = ceil(3*rand); %// 1,2,3 with equal probability
B = ceil(3*rand); %// 1,2,3 with equal probability, independent from A
notAB = setdiff(1:3,union(A,B)); %// allowed values for C
indC = ceil(rand*numel(notAB)); %// select one of them, with equal probability
C = notAB(indC);
```

---

In this case it may be simpler to explicitly write all allowed combinations and select one of them randomly:

```
template = [1 1 2
            1 1 3
            1 2 3
            1 3 2
            2 1 3
            2 2 1
            2 2 3
            2 3 1
            3 1 2
            3 2 1
            3 3 1
            3 3 2];
ind = ceil(rand*size(template,1));
A = template(ind,1);
B = template(ind,2);
C = template(ind,3);
```

Comment: @Edric Because old versions of Matlab don't have it. Since the OP uses `rand`, I'm assuming perhaps they don't have `randi`